# ng-options where selection of one determines options of the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-options

I have two dropdowns, and I want the second one to have only the options that are relevant to the selected item in the first.  I could do some ng-change function but am trying to get it to work with only code in html, and am close but not quite.

I tried what is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130825/angularjs-conditional-display-for-ng-options) but it's not quite working.  It shows all options instead of none for Level 2 when no selection is made for Level 1, and when a selection is made for Level 1, it only shows the first valid option for Level 2.  I'd like, if a is selected for Level 1, it should show b, c, d, e as options for Level 2, and if z is selected, it should show c, d, f, g as options for Level 2.

Here is my code in plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DuCMjAUKTBiGJNQfhVbd?p=preview

Here is my javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui', 'ui.filters']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.myFilters = [
    {level1:'a',level2:'b'},
    {level1:'a',level2:'c'},
    {level1:'a',level2:'d'},
    {level1:'a',level2:'e'},
    {level1:'z',level2:'c'},
    {level1:'z',level2:'d'},
    {level1:'z',level2:'f'},
    {level1:'z',level2:'g'},
    ];
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
  <form>
  Level 1:
  <select name="level1" ng-model="level1selection" ng-options="myFilter.level1 for myFilter in myFilters | unique:'level1'"></select>
  <br />

  Level 2:
  <select name="level2" ng-model="level2selection" ng-options="myFilter.level2 for myFilter in myFilters | filter:myFilter.level1=level1selection | unique:'level2'"></select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is common between level1 and level2?

Comment: Nothing - essentially I want the Level 2 dropdown to contain the result of "select level2 from myFilters where level1 = _the_users_level_1_selection_" if I was writing SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a small change that makes my example work, by changing this:

```
<select name="level2" ng-model="level2selection" ng-options="myFilter.level2 for myFilter in myFilters | filter:myFilter.level1=level1selection | unique:'level2'"></select>
```

to this:

```
<select name="level2" ng-model="level2selection" ng-options="myFilter.level2 for myFilter in myFilters | filter:myFilter.level1=level1selection.level1 | unique:'level2'"></select>
```

It seems like the value of the selection was the first entire row in my "table" as opposed to just the displayed value.  Not sure if there is a way to set the ng-model to just the displayed value directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* to hook all this up from the template but the expressions get very confusing. At the end of the day I think it's actually more "declarative" to indicate exactly what's about to happen with an ngChange directive. See working Plunkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WJ91H0NmiRcOY6H5lpTE?p=preview

Basically, all you're doing is changing your data structure to look more like this:

```
$scope.options = {
  'a': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  'z': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
};
```

You can also do this in many other ways and this method is going to work. For example, your level1 and level2 lists can be completely separate structures. That's pretty typical for most apps with nested lists of options because each option is going to be some table of entries in a database or similar.

Then you just use an ng-change triggered off the user selecting an option in the first combo box:

```
$scope.level1Change = function() {
  $scope.level2 = $scope.options[$scope.level1selection];
}
```

This is an extra few lines of code, sure, but it still honors all of AngularJS's principles, it's clear and easy to understand... and it's actually much more efficient because the expressions are simpler and there are no filters required. If you change your original filter expression to call a function of your own, and put a console.log() on it, you'll be shocked at how often it gets called.

Angular doesn't really have a good way to tell when it needs to call a filter so it tends to call them a LOT more than you'd think. Basically anything that triggers a digest is going to trigger this, even if the user isn't touching these form elements.

If you REALLY want to get rid of this callback you can do exactly the same thing in your HTML template, like this:

```
<select name="level1" ng-model="level1selection"
        ng-options="level1 as level1 for (level1, level2) in options"
        ng-change="level2 = options[level1selection];"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to change

```
filter:myFilter.level1=level1selection
```

to

```
filter:{level1:level1selection.level1}
```

thats it.

```
<form>
      Level 1:
      <select name="level1" ng-model="level1selection" ng-options="myFilter.level1 for myFilter in myFilters | unique:'level1'"></select>
      <br />
      Level 2:
      <select name="level2" ng-model="level2selection" 
         ng-options="myFilter.level2 for myFilter in myFilters | filter:{level1:level1selection.level1}"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.